# Compile from linux for windows in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile my project in eclipse(linux) for windows.
I followed a guide, then I'm able to compile for windows from command line. I tried to create my project using GCC-toolchain and selecting my prefix/directory

Output on the eclipse console is:

```
Building file: ../src/provagcc2.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/provagcc2.d" -MT"src/provagcc2.o" -o "src/provagcc2.o" "../src/provagcc2.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/provagcc2.cpp

Building target: provagcc2
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++  -o "provagcc2"  ./src/provagcc2.o   
Finished building target: provagcc2
```

however, it generates a .o file instead of a .exe

Comment: Path of least resistance is just compiling on the target OS (natively or in a VM). Cross compiling is a pain and usually more pain to get working than it's worth. Just my $0.02.

Comment: To back up Jesper's comment, I use VMs for exactly this reason plus one added incentive: Once the project is "done" and goes into maintenance, the VM preserves the build environment so those who follow me (or me) don't have to waste time setting up an identical system to pick up where I left off. IDEs get upgraded, PCs die, tools change. If you find yourself having to work on a 25-year-old project and can't bring the software into to the modern world for one reason or another, there's the virtual machine all ready to get up and get debugging.

Answer (score 0):

`-o "provagcc2"` looks like you did not specify an extension for the output. There should also be a provagcc2 without extension lying around somewhere as a result. The provagcc2.o file you have found is likely the is the result of compiling. provagcc2.cpp

`-o "provagcc2.exe"` is what you want on the command line.

To tell Eclipse to name the file correctly, you need to navigate to *Project->Properties* on the menu. In the Properties dialog that pops up, expand *C/C++ Build* and select *Settings*. Select the *Build Artifact* tab and type *exe* into the *Artifact extension* field. *Apply and Close* and rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks, it compiles, however the .exe doesn't run. I tried it with wine (but also in windows) and : `002e:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\me\\eclipse-workspace\\provagcc2\\Debug\\provagcc2.exe") not found
002e:err:module:attach_dlls Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\me\\eclipse-workspace\\provagcc2\\Debug\\provagcc2.exe" failed, status c0000135`. However, the .exe compiled from command line works fine

Comment: @siruvio You can carry around the standard library DLLs with your code, but it is probably better to statically link them so you don't have to worry about them at all.  Your executable will be much, much bigger, but it will be stand-alone. Navigate *Project->Properties*, *expand C/C++ Build* and select *Settings*. On the *Tool Settings* tab, expand the (probably) *Mingw C++ Linker* and select *Miscellaneous*. Type *-static* into the *Linker flags* field. *Apply and Close* and rebuild the project.

Comment: It works with an "hello world". I Tried with a more complex project (I included library CLP) and got `In file included from /opt/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/4.9.0/cstdio:42:0,
                 from /home/me/coin-Clp/CoinUtils/src/CoinMessageHandler.hpp:13,
                 from /home/me/coin-Clp/Clp/src/ClpModel.hpp:20,
                 from /home/me/coin-Clp/Clp/src/ClpSimplex.hpp:16,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:71:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef __ssize_t ssize_t’
 typedef __ssize_t ssize_t;`

Comment: @siruvio Recommend asking a new question about that one as it is too different from the current question to be on topic. It looks like there may be two definitions of `__ssize_t `, but I'd need to see it in context and with the full, formatted error message. There is probably more to that message; the compiler usually tells you where to find the other half of the collision.

Comment: Ok, I did it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842222/conflicting-declarations-in-eclipse-c